# Cannot reload table view in IOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am a quite new to IOS development and keep having struggle with it. I would like to display phone list which an user has from my server but tableview does not display items. I have got data from server well and I think settings for UItableView is correct. Here is my code:

STKPhoneHolderViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "STKSimpleHttpClientDelegate.h"

@interface STKPhoneHolderViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, STKSimpleHttpClientDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *phoneTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *phoneArray;

@end
```

STKPhoneHolderViewController.m

```
@implementation STKPhoneHolderViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.phoneTable.dataSource = self;
    self.phoneArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self loadPhoneList];

}


#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.phoneArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhoneCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

        STKPhoneHolder *phoneHolder = [self.phoneArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setText:phoneHolder.userName];


    return cell;
}

#pragma Custom method
- (void) loadPhoneList
{

    self.phoneArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    STKSimpleHttpClient *client = [[STKSimpleHttpClient alloc]init];
    client.delegate = self;

    NSString *userId = @"your_id_h";

    NSString *sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?userid=%@",
                      MOBILE_API_URL,
                      PHONEHOLDER_URI,
                      userId];

    [client send:sUrl data:@""];
}

#pragma STKSimpleHttpClientDelegate
-(void) complete:(STKHttpResult*) result
{
     if (result.ok != YES){
         [STKUtility alert:result.message];
         return;
     }

    self.phoneArray = (NSMutableArray*)result.result;
    for (STKPhoneHolder *holder in self.phoneArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [holder description]);
    }

    [self.phoneTable reloadData];
    NSLog(@" isMainThread(%d)", [NSThread isMainThread] );
}


@end
```

STKSimpleHttpClient.m

```
#import "STKSimpleHttpClient.h"
#import "STKSimpleHttpClientDelegate.h"

@implementation STKSimpleHttpClient

NSMutableData *responseData;
STKHttpResult *httpResult;


void (^completeFunction)(STKHttpResult *);

- (void) send:(NSString*)url
         data:(NSString*)data
{
    httpResult = [[STKHttpResult alloc]init];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if ( data == nil) return;

        //Get request object and set properties
        NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
        //set header for JSON request and response
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        //set http method to POST
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        //set time out
        [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:20];

        NSData *body = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //set request body
        urlRequest.HTTPBody = body;

        //connect to server
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        if (conn==nil){
            //Do something
        }
    });
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
    // so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
    // Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
    // also serves to clear it
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    // Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable noow
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    BOOL ok = [[json objectForKey:@"ok"] boolValue];
    NSString *message = [json objectForKey:@"message"];
    if (ok == NO) {
        [httpResult setError:message];
    } else {
        [httpResult setSuccess:[json objectForKey:@"result"]];
    }

    if (self.delegate !=nil) {
        [self.delegate complete:httpResult];
    }

    responseData = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // The request has failed for some reason!
    // Check the error var
    if (self.delegate !=nil) {
        [self.delegate complete:[httpResult setError:@"Connection failed."]];
    }
}
```

STKPhoneHolder.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface STKPhoneHolder : NSObject

@property NSString *deviceId;
@property NSString *userId;
@property NSString *userName;
@property NSString *msn;

- (id) initWithDeviceId:(NSString*)aDeviceId
                 userId:(NSString*)aUserId
            userName:(NSString*)aUserName
            msn:(NSString*)aMsn;

@end
```

Log:

```
2013-12-17 16:14:23.447 [5323:70b] {
    deviceId = 11111;
    email = "";
    msn = 11111111;
    role = "";
    userId = aaaaaa;
    userName = "Joshua Pak";
}
2013-12-17 16:14:23.448 [5323:70b] {
    deviceId = 22222;
    email = "";
    msn = 2222222;
    role = "";
    userId = bbbbb;
    userName = "Jasdf Pak";
}
2013-12-17 16:14:23.449 Stalker[5323:70b]  isMainThread(1)
```

I can see the log printing phoneArray with two phones in 'complete' method but tableview just display "No record". Tableview does not render again even though I called reloadData method. I made sure that [self.phoneTable reloadData] is called in debugging mode.
What do I have to do more?

Comment: @MaKo the datasource is set, why setting the delegate?

Comment: You don't need to  create an outlet to the table view. A table view controller already has a tableView property (did you connect your phoneTable outlet in IB?). Try replacing any self.phoneTable references with self.tableView

Comment: In numberOfRowsInSection, put in an NSLog and print self.phoneArray count.  Is it displaying a non-zero?

Comment: Add a `NSLog(@"my table: %@", self.phoneTable);` in `viewDidLoad` and validate it not being `nil`.

Comment: Why do you `alloc init` phone array just before calling `loadPhoneList` and then again as the first line of the method?

Comment: @Til, thanks so much. It is null. I already set the tableview in storyboard and it is linked to the IBOutlet in STKPhoneHolderViewController.h. I do not understand why it is null.
It looks strange IOS does not return exception even though I call method of null instance.

Answer (score 3):

Try to call reloadData in main thread

```
#pragma STKSimpleHttpClientDelegate
-(void) complete:(STKHttpResult*) result
{
     if (result.ok != YES){
         [STKUtility alert:result.message];
         return;
     }

    self.phoneArray = (NSMutableArray*)result.result;

    for (STKPhoneHolder *holder in self.phoneArray) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [holder description]);
        }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.phoneTable reloadData];
    }
}
```

Or you can use performSelectorOnMainThread

```
[self.phoneTable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                 withObject:nil
                              waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I am guessing STKSimpleHttpClient class is calling complete delegate function on different thread, all user interface interaction suppose to be called from main thread.

Try this code to see which thread you are in from the complete delegate function

```
NSLog(@" isMainThread(%d)", [NSThread isMainThread] );
```

Comment: +1 Seems like a good guess - should be worth double-checking.

Comment: I added STKSimpleHttpClient. Sorry, your code does not work. I removed dispatch_async from send method of STKSimpleHttpClient.m but still same.

Answer (score 0):

check this. does the code load the tableview before you get information from web services. if so then write the statement [tableview Reload]; next to the  web services information getting process. This will help

Answer (score -1):

It's not necessary to specify the number of sections, but you might want to do it with this code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary. The default is 1.

Comment: I did it in the storyboard, do I have to do it again in the source code as well? And I cannot display No record anyway instead of the phoneArray, it means method you mentioned does not have something with my problem. Finally, I added your code but it did not work. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Did you set the number of sections in Storyboard? By any chance did you also set to Static Table instead of Dynamic? It should be the latter.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I did not set prototype cells in storyboard. Anyway, I added your code but it did not work.
UITableView is Dynamic Prototypes, Multiple Selection and other properties are default.

Answer (score -1):

I see you're using a Table View Controller, which already has a tableView reference `self.tableView`.

Like @rdelmar said, you could use that reference instead of your phoneTable:

```
[[self tableView] setDataSource:self];
[[self tableView] setDelegate:self];
[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

Comment: This is something the OP should do, but it wouldn't cause his problem. The methods he's using are data source methods, not delegate methods.

Comment: redlmar You are correct.  @Guilherme, sorry, your code does not work.