# Why UITableView is null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have asked my tableview did not reload data. The problem was phoneTable property in STKPhoneHolderViewController.h was null. But I cannot understand why this happened because I linked tableview in storyboard to IBOutlet variable as below image.

[image]

Is this a bug in Xcode or did I miss something? Your answer would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the previous question:
[Cannot reload table view in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623575/cannot-reload-table-view-in-ios7)

Comment: When did you try to reload it? Can you show that code, and what method it is in?

Comment: I added the previous question link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a UITableViewController which already has a UITableView (see the main view is also a Table View). My guess is by adding a second tableview the delegate and datasource methods are being called for both tableviews but the original tableview is null.

Delete your second tableview or switch to using a UIViewController

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like the right one. I will try it and give you feedback.

Comment: I removed the existing view controller and created new UITableViewController and accessed by self.tableView and I can get tableView now. Thanks again, but this time I have an exception saying "[__NSCFDictionary userName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d9cfd0". I am gonna search about this and I will post my question if I cannot any solution.